# How to create own login method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using passport package in my project. Everything is working fine. I need custom functionality in which I can login through `provider_id` instead of `email` and `password`.

The below code is working absolutely fine

```
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'fail',
                'message' => 'The given data was invalid.'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;

        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
            $token->save();
```

I want to have same functionality as like below

```
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

But through `provider_id`, and I can use these input for login which are in same `users

```
name
provider
provider_id
```

can someone kindly guide me about that I would appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Authenticate A User By ID**

To log a user into the application by their ID, you may use the `loginUsingId` method. This method accepts the primary key of the user you wish to authenticate:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

You can make some changes in the same method or you can create your own custom login method as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but the answer is not fulfill my requirements it is totally something else. I wounder who voted-up. Totally irrelevant answer

Comment: Please let me know how this is *irrelevant answer* for you?

Comment: @ScriptLover - This is definitely relevant to the question you've posted. Just query the database using the fields you want, like `$provider_id`, get the users ID and use the above to log the user in.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson As you can see I am looking for the solution which is totally different. I know how to  Authenticate a user by id which is not fulfill my requirements. That's why I try to explain in question you can review it again. Thank you.

Comment: @ScriptLover - I still don't see it as totally different. The above is a solution (although, you would need to write some additional code). The `attempt()` method is a convenient method to authenticate a user using an identifier (like username) and their password. If that's not what you want to do (since you want to authenticate using `$provider_id`, that's not the method you want to use. If that's not what you're after, then the question is unclear.